Run odoo tests in odoo sh
anyone know how to run odoo custom test cases(test cases from custom module) on odoo.sh while build on odoo sh?
Odoo custom test cases not working in odoo.sh while build
I tried test cases on my custom module but not able to build those test cases in odoo.sh. can anyone help how to do it? thanks in advance.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

To run tests in Odoo:

Launch Odoo using --test-enable parameter (and use the "-d [my_database]" flag to specify the database you want to test)
Use the -i [modules_to_install] flag to set the modules that you want to test.
To execute a test on your local Odoo installation, use this command:

    ./odoo-bin -i {module_to_install} --test-enable -c {conf path}


in the terminal, you can use this command to run the tests in a particular module:

    ./odoo-bin -c /path/to/odoo.conf -d your_database_name -u your_module_name --test-enable

You can run both the QUnit test case and the tours test case from the UI. It is not possible to run Python test cases from the UI as it runs on the server side. In order to see the options to run test cases from the UI, you need to enable developer mode.
The developer mode is also available with assets, which are used to debug JavaScript code, and with tests assets, which are used to run test tours.
Click on the bug icon to open the drop-down menu, Click on the Run JS Tests option. This will open the QUnit suite and it will start running the test cases one by one. y default, it will only show failed test cases. To show all the passed test cases, uncheck the Hide passed tests checkbox.
To run tour from the UI:
Activate developer mode and click on the bug icon and then click on Start Tour. This will open the dialog with a list of registered tours. Click on the play button on the side to run the tour.
